# how can i find a list item with a list item's given parameter?

Tags: c#, linq, list, search

how can i find a list item with a list item's given parameter?

my list is defined as;

```
public List<Column0A> list0A = new List<Column0A>();
```

and has items as;

```
list0A.Add(new Column0A(header.type, message.receieveTime, message.importance, message.data));
```

i have listed all the message.receiveTime's on my GUI depending on my list. what i really want is;
when a user click on receiveTime label, i want to show a tooltip which shows the list item's (same receive time) all data like this:

> Header: header.type
>
> Receive Time: receiveTime
>
> Importance: message.Importance
>
> Data: message.data

how can i find the same receieveTime list instance? should i use LINQ?
could you give me a code sample?

thanks.

Comment: `list0A` is a really bad variable name - you should give you variables (and methods, and classes and....) meaningful names.

Comment: You also shouldn't have public fields.  That should be a property.  For even better form, it shouldn't return `List<T>`, but an interface, such as `IList<T>`, so that the implementation could be switched out without major refactoring.

Comment: Oded, it is meaningful to me; it is a list which holds 0A messages. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you use an ID as the lookup instead of the time stamp.  If this info comes from a database, this would probably be the primary key field.  It makes your intent clearer, and allows you to select the right info if two happen to have the same time.  Then to select your item:

```
int theIdImLookingFor = //the one they just clicked on
Column0A myItem = list0A.Single(x => x.ID == theIdImLookingFor);
//display myItem's info in a tooltip
```

(`Single` is a LINQ extension) If you're not already clear on it, you should study the difference between `Single`, `First`, `SingleOrDefault`, and `FirstOrDefault`, and choose the one appropriate for you situation.

Comment: If there is no database with a primary key, the OP could also generate a `Guid` in his in memory `Column0A` class as it is populated. The unique ID can be assigned to the label's `Tag` field. When the label is clicked on, use the value in the `Tag` field as Tim S. code `theIdImLookingFor` as well as the rest of his code.

Comment: thanks Tim S., it really helped me, i appretiated. 
also thanks Brad Rem for additional information.